# p:collector display only one record

Tags: primefaces

I test the example of `p:collector` on the primefaces site but it didn't work for me,
the add button only added one record, when I add a second, the datatable display only the lastest one.

NB: I have added `ajax="false"` for the add button, if not, the button doesn't work.

Comment: I'm just too tired to ask for the code,version...it's up to you!

Comment: Please post your code and which version of PrimeFaces you're using. Without the code we cannot see what is causing the problem. Since you didn't supply anything I'm downvoting this question.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, sorry for my english But I have not learned at all. 
I just changed THE SCOPE OF MY BEAN it was @RequestScoped And I CHANGE IT to:

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

The entity class  has the @override methods, which were generated while creating new entity through create new entity wizard. remove all the overridden methods from the entity and save it. Thats all. Now it will work.

Comment: What do you base this on? The OP didn't post code, are you psychic?

Comment: I was wondering that myself, as I read the question and saw an answer.